# Need help creating a relational database table

Tags: mysql

What would be the best way to create a relational flow for these tables? 
It's basically a flow for a checklist and these are the tables i want to relate. (the category and item table are preset values that people can select).

Which of the tables should i put the userID to link them? Attached find the screenshot.
Here an overview of the relationship i did:
// category Table
category_id (PK)
...
...

// item Table
item_id (PK)
category_id (FK)
...

*NB: i'm relatively new to databases*
[database flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AejXN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you intended to store user cat/item selections, you may create another table such as "USER_SELECTION" (*** assuming single selection for each) with at least user id, cat id, item id for this table. As you may have guessed it, here all IDs are forign keys to respective tables, and the combination of the three is the primary key.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use transaction table to relate user, category and item. JOIN QUERY will help you. Use these sql queries to create your tables.

```
CREATE TABLE user_table( useriD int auto_increment primary key, Name varchar(100), email varchar(256), password varchar(50));

CREATE TABLE category_table ( catiD int auto_increment primary key, categoryName varchar(50));

CREATE TABLE item_table (itemiD int auto_increment primary key, catID int not null, item_name varchar(50));

CREATE TABLE transaction ( transaction_id int auto_increment primary key, userID not null, catID not null, itemID int not null)
```